# Find top 3 most frequent store by each client

Tags: sql, ranking

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9wZj.png)

**Table as it is**

| Client | Store | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | ABC | 10 |
| Peter | ABC | 10 |
| Peter | ABC | 10 |
| Peter | ABC | 10 |
| Peter | 7eleven | 5 |
| Peter | 7eleven | 5 |
| Peter | 7eleven | 5 |
| Peter | Addidas | 64 |
| Peter | Addidas | 64 |
| Peter | Nike | 52 |
| Ben | 7eleven | 5 |
| Ben | 7eleven | 7 |
| Ben | 7eleven | 7 |
| Ben | 7eleven | 3 |
| Ben | Nike | 48 |
| Ben | Nike | 48 |
| Ben | Nike | 48 |
| Ben | Puma | 67 |
| Ben | Puma | 67 |
| Ben | Addidas | 55 |
| Ben | ABC | 12 |
| Diana | Puma | 58 |
| Diana | Puma | 58 |
| Diana | Puma | 58 |
| Diana | Puma | 42 |
| Diana | ABC | 12 |
| Diana | ABC | 12 |
| Diana | ABC | 12 |
| Diana | Sony | 230 |
| Diana | Sony | 130 |
| Kate | Zara | 58 |
| Kate | Zara | 58 |
| Kate | Zara | 58 |
| Kate | Zara | 42 |
| Kate | Post | 12 |
| Kate | Post | 12 |
| Kate | Post | 12 |
| Kate | LG | 230 |
| Kate | LG | 130 |
| Kate | ABC | 12 |

**The result I try to get**

| Client | Store | Rank Most friquent Store |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | ABC | 1 |
| Peter | 7eleven | 2 |
| Peter | Addidas | 3 |
| Ben | 7eleven | 1 |
| Ben | Nike | 2 |
| Ben | Puma | 3 |
| Diana | Puma | 1 |
| Diana | ABC | 2 |
| Diana | Sony | 3 |
| Kate | Zara | 1 |
| Kate | Post | 2 |
| Kate | LG | 3 |

I tried the following script, but it doesn't work

```
Select * 
From (SELECT client, store, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY client, store ORDER BY COUNT(store) DESC) AS RN
      FROM my.table) as TMP_TBL
WHERE RN<4
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate DBMS (MySQL, SQL-Server, PostgreSQL etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is almost correct; your problem is that you only need to partition by `Client`, not `Client` and `Store`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT Client, Store, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY COUNT(Store) DESC) AS RN
  FROM my_table
  GROUP BY Client, Store
  ) t
WHERE RN < 4
```

Output for your sample data:

```
Client  Store   RN
Ben     7eleven 1
Ben     Nike    2
Ben     Puma    3
Diana   Puma    1
Diana   ABC     2
Diana   Sony    3
Kate    Zara    1
Kate    Post    2
Kate    LG      3
Peter   ABC     1
Peter   7eleven 2
Peter   Addidas 3
```

[Demo on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aFKSe4dTmfm2jN4NXsvNo2/0)